# The following issues were found during validation during my iOS app submission to the app store

Tags: ios, xcode

I have tried to submit my app to the app store and i get the following errors

missing routing app coverage file

nib file iPad-Nib

invalid info.Plist
[image: a screen shot of the error]

i dont know why the iPad error is there as my app is an iPhone app

and the other two im not sure how to create an map routing file
and not sure how to correct the p.list error

Comment: And you don't have universal selected rather than just iPhone in the general section?

Comment: nope but i did do at one point. just to try something so i looked in to the plist only to find the ipad setting still in there i deleted it and all is fine. as for the missing routing file i just had to uncheck the routing methods in the settings of the app. ie car bike waking etc